# Merge indexed arrays from POST request

Tags: php

I have this array coming from post request:

```
$x = [
  "meal" => [
    "monday" => [
      "breakfast" => [
        0 => "type1",
        1 => "type1",
      ],
      "afternoonTea" => [
        0 => "type2",
      ],
    ],
  ],
  "number" => [
    "monday" => [
      "breakfast" => [
        0 => "10",
        1 => "9",
      ],
      "afternoonTea" => [
        0 => "1",
      ],
    ],
  ],
];
```

I am trying to merge all this into one array without using tones of foreaches.
Maybe someone more clever will know how to use iterators to achieve that.

Data from `meal` and `number` is always `1:1`.
I need to convert this to something like this:

```
$x = [
    "monday" => [
      "breakfast" => [
        [
            'type' => "type1",
            'number' => 10,
        ],
        [
            'type' => "type1",
            'number' => 9
        ]
      ],
      "afternoonTea" => [
        [
            'type' => "type2",
            'number' => 1,
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ],
];
```

Comment: I suppose you need to restructure your form than this array.

Comment: Why don't you want to use multiple foreach?

Comment: @Pipe personally (my opinion) multiple foreaches are nasty. I suggest to optimize your array like u_mulder says.

Comment: My firends, now I need 3 foreaches to achieve that. I pretty sure that changing this structure will not help. Currently it is `field[day][meal][]`, changing to `day[meal][field][]` will lead me to exact same 3 foreaches. So if you can suggest better structure, I will be happy. Remember there can be `n` `type+value` values for each `meal` (`[]`)

Answer (score 1):

If you count 3 as being tonnes then this isn't your answer - but I can't see a way of reducing down the number of reach loops below this without getting to a game of code golf which won't be helpful.

Because you know there is a 1:1 relationship between `meal` and `number`, you can use the indexes from one to get data from the other by doing:

```
$result = [];
foreach($x['meal'] as $day => $list) {
    foreach($list as $activity => $types) {
        foreach($types as $i => $type) {
            $result[$day][$activity][] = [
                'type' => $type,
                'value' => $x['number'][$day][$activity][$i],
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this will be `$result` will contain the array in the format you want.